# Multiple S3 credentials in a Spark Structured Streaming application

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-structured-streaming, ceph

I want to migrate our Delta lake from S3 to Parquet files in our own on-prem Ceph storage, both accessible through the S3-compliant s3a API in Spark. Is there a possibility to provide different credentials for `readStream` and `writeStream` to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the s3a connector supports per-bucket configuration, so you can declare a different set of secrets, endpoint etc for your internal buckets from your external ones.

consult the hadoop s3a docs for the normative details and examples